# install g++ without update glibc

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, glibc

I need to compile a c++ project with glibc 2.13 version. I found out that Ubuntu 11.10 has the verison of the glibc that i'm searching.

So i installed it in my virtual machine, and then i installed g++ compiler with:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

The problem is that g++ package updates also glib to the lastest version of glibc 2.19.

I tried also to compile the source of glibc2.13 but i get different errors in compiling, because for sure i need to use the same version of compiler used when it was been created.

I think that the fastest way is to use glibc 2.13, already installed on Ubuntu 11.10. So i need to find out a solution to install g++ without update glibc.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, fetch a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 4.9  source [tarball](ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-4.9.1/gcc-4.9.1.tar.bz2) (and all the dependencies, perhaps using `aptitude build-dep gcc` or the `contrib/download_prerequisites` script inside GCC source tree) and compile it and [install](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) it from its source code (using your installed `glibc-2.13`...). You need to configure it (perhaps passing something like `--program-suffix=-4.9-mine` and possibly some `--prefix`) and build it *outside* of its source tree then install it. (then use `g++-4.9-mine` as your C++ compiler). Read and follow *carefully* the [installation instructions](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/)

<sup>Running `gcc -v` will show you how your system GCC was configured.</sup>

BTW I am not sure that the version of glibc always matter that much (it really depends of a lot of factors). Did you try to compile your project (on whatever Linux system you have) and run it on a machine (perhaps a virtual one) with glibc 2.13? It might work (but I am not sure at all)!

Comment: Thank you Basile, but once that i have compiled the gcc, i need to copy and replace my older gcc? And i will get also g++ ready to run? If i run my project compiled with a new version of glibc, in the machine with glibc2.13 i get an error occured by the version of glibc, and it suggest me to recompile the project in a glibc2.13.

Comment: Yes, you'll get both a `gcc-4.9-mine` and a `g++-4.9-mine` if you configure GCC correctly for that. Don't forget to build GCC *outside* of its source tree! Read carefully the installation instructions!

Comment: Basile i've tried to compile the source, but i get the following error: `no usable dependecy style found`, relative to dependecy style of g++. I did not find any information about it, but it looks be an error of the compiler that i'm currently using. There is any way to download just g++ package, without and not the entire gcc package?

Comment: No, g++ is part of GCC (like gcc is)

Comment: I get the following error: checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error; and i find out that to run it i need g++ installed. So at the end to compile gcc pakcage you need g++, but to install g++, i update also the glibc version, so this way is not giving me any solution.

Comment: Hi find a different solution compiling the library as static. In this i should not get compatibility errors with old glibc.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain special version from Ubuntu toolchain ppa repo:

#cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-precise.list

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu precise main
```

## Gcc 4.9

Pre build steps:

```
apt-get build-dep -y gcc-4.9-multilib
apt-get source -y gcc-4.9-multilib
dpkg-source -x gcc-4.9_4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04.dsc
cd gcc-4.9-4.9.2
```

customized parameters:

```
mkdir -p src && tar -xf gcc-*.tar.xz -C src
cd src && ./contrib/download_prerequisites && cd ..
mkdir -p /opt/dev-tools-4.9
../src/configure --prefix=//opt/dev-tools-4.9 \
-v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04' \
--program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib \
--libexecdir=//opt/dev-tools-4.9/lib --without-included-gettext \
--enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=//opt/dev-tools-4.9/include/c++/4.9 \
--libdir=//opt/dev-tools-4.9/lib --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes \
--enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror \
--with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --with-tune=generic \
--enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu  --with-sysroot=/  --enable-nls

make -j $(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo ) && make install
```

Also you should rebuild the binutils:

## binutils 2.22

```
apt-get build-dep -y binutils-dev
apt-get source -y  binutils-dev
dpkg-source -x binutils_2.22-6ubuntu1.3.dsc
  mkdir  objdir&& cd objdir

 ../binutils-2.22/configure --prefix=/opt/rdwr_tools/radware-dev-tools-4.9            \
--exec-prefix=/opt/rdwr_tools/radware-dev-tools-4.9       \
 --with-sysroot=/   --enable-multilib     \
 --with-lib-path=/opt/rdwr_tools/radware-dev-tools-4.9/lib \
 --disable-werror  --enable-shared \
 --enable-targets=x86_64-linux-gnu,i686-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-mingw32,i686-pc-mingw32
make -j 8 && make install
```